# Freopen causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, freopen

Got any ideas why this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int nrpart;
int k;

void main()
{
    printf("lol");
    freopen("p2.in","r",stdin);
    freopen("p2.out","w",stdout);
    printf("roar");
}
```

outputs only lol? I used freopen some other times but it doesn't seem to be working now and I really can't tell why.

Comment: This program looks fine. Can you tell which `freopen()` causes the segfault? Ideally you'll step through with a debugger.

Comment: Check the return value of the `freopen`. May be some trouble with presmissions?

Comment: this is the whole code that seg faults? It seems to work fine for me.

Comment: as a side note, avoid using `void main ()`

Answer (score 3):

Check out the file `p2.out`. The text printed by second call to `printf` is there, cause you redirected standard output to that file. There was no segmentation violation. Good joke, though.

Answer (score 0):

Your code as written, does not cause a segmentation fault (for me at least). Not sure how it's doing that for you unless there's more that you're not showing.

Make sure you check out some [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/freopen/) on `freopen()`, specifically the part about the return values:

> If the file is successfully reopened, the function returns the pointer passed as parameter stream, which can be used to identify the reopened stream.
>    Otherwise, a null pointer is returned.
>    On most library implementations, the errno variable is also set to a system-specific error code on failure.

So make sure you're checking the return values and the errno value before using your newly redirected streams. Could be the cause of your error.

If your code segfaulted prior to the line `printf("roar");`, well, that would be why you're not seeing it. If it segfaulted after that then your "roar" should be in the file `p2.out`.

An important note: Remember to `fclose` `stdin` and `stdout` at the end of your program! These are now redirected to `p2.in` and `p2.out` respectively and need to be closed when you're done with them.